# Removal of item from ko.observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to remove an object from an ko.observableArray
I have two observableArrays

```
self.arrayA = ko.observableArray();
self.arrayB = ko.observableArray();
```

then in a function I want to remove an item.

```
self.myRemoval = function(item){
    var arrayToRemoveFrom;
    if ( somelogic ) {
        arrayToRemoveFrom = self.arrayA();  
    }
    else {
        arrayToRemoveFrom = self.arrayB(); 
    }
    arrayToRemoveFrom.remove(item);   
}
```

The line "arrayToRemoveFrom.remove(item)" causes an exception, saying remove is not a function. What would be the best way to remove "item"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`remove` is a [special function of the `ko.onservableArray`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#remove-and-removeall) .

However when you write `self.arrayA();` with the `()` at the end you are returning the underlaying JavaScript array which does not have a `remove` function and you get the exception.

To fix your code you just need to remove the `()`:

```
self.myRemoval = function(item){
    var arrayToRemoveFrom;
    if ( somelogic ) {
        arrayToRemoveFrom = self.arrayA;  
    }
    else {
        arrayToRemoveFrom = self.arrayB; 
    }
    arrayToRemoveFrom.remove(item);   
}
```

Comment: Excellent. So easy. Thanx, nemesv! :)